# Localizable.strings with UILineBreakModeWordWrap

Tags: ios, xcode, text, localization, uilabel

The set Localizable.strings when word length is too much difference,

I want to set a dynamic can be rendered in accordance with the number of words UILabel 
and has to calculating the distance with last UILabel.

Please give me some advice，Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
textthird.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
textthird.numberOfLines = 0;
CGSize size3 = CGSizeMake(285,2000); 
CGSize labelsize3 = [NSLocalizedString(@"text_third",nil) sizeWithFont:textthird.font constrainedToSize:size3 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap]; 
[textthird setFrame:CGRectMake(25,labelsize.height+160,labelsize3.width,labelsize3.height)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it from Localizable.string. This file only carries your strings. 
Typically you would do this in your interface code.